# Get Media model by ID and use it to make a downloadable URL doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

In my CustomProduct model I have multiple media's
When I fire a GET request I add the product id & the media id.

When I try the following code below, It's a Eloquent Collection. but I need it to be a Media model because I can't call ->getPath() now.

```
public function downloadMedia($customProduct, $mediaItemId) {
    $product = CustomProduct::find($customProduct);
    $mediaCollection = $product->getMedia('notes');

    $mediaItem = $mediaCollection->where('id', $mediaItemId);

    return response()->download($mediaItem->getPath(), $mediaItem->file_name);
}
```

expected: I redirect to the page and a downloaded file model opens

actual result: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getPath does not exist. because it's a Collection not a Media model.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to get the Media model was changing the following

```
$mediaItem = $mediaCollection->where('id', $mediaItemId);
```

to

```
$mediaItem = $mediaCollection->where('id', $mediaItemId)->first();
```